# jquery .html(); not replacing the text block

Tags: jquery, html

The last line of my jQuery code not working for the unknown reason, it has to replace the **'content'**  block in my div panel (**panel-body**) to  the new string **"My New Awesome Content"** from the variable (**var content = "My New Awesome Content";**). If  someone helps me clarify what's going on with my code and why it's not working? I appreciate any help!

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var content = "My New Awesome Content";

        $('.panel-button').on('click', function() { 
            var panelId = $(this).attr('data-panelid');
            $('#'+panelId).toggle();
            **$('#'+panelId+'.panel-body').html(content);**

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to select an element with id `panelId` and class `panel-body` and jQuery returns an empty list, so nothing happens.

Leave a space before `.panel-body` so you can select an element with class `panel-body` **inside** an element with id `panelID`:

```
$('#' + panelId + ' .panel-body').html(content);
```

**NOTE**

In case you want to target only immediate children with class `panel-body` of a div with specific id, you have to use `>` selector or use `children()` method:

**CSS selector**

```
$('#' + panelId + ' > .panel-body').html(content);
```

**children()**

```
$('#' + panelId + '').children('.panel-body').html(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You skipped a space between the element and its child:

```
$('#'+panelId+' .panel-body').html(content);
```

The way you're doing will make a filter in your `panelId` to select the ones that has a `panel-body` class.